# How can I nest a function within my C program?

Tags: c

does anyone know how I could change my code to include a function that averages each line of the table (instead of being done in the main function)? Every time I try running my code with the process_student function, it doesn't print the table at all. I have included my working "non-function" code first, followed by my failed code that includes the process_student function. Thanks in advance!

Also, I am using a redirected input .txt file!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

int month = 0;
int date = 0;
int year = 0;
int x = 0;
int id = 0;
int min_user = 0;
int ms = 0;
int realTest = 0;
float min = 10000000;
float t1 = 0;
float t2 = 0; 
float t3 = 0;
float t4 = 0;
float avg_trial = 0;

scanf("%d %d %d", &month, &date, &year);
printf("\nStudy Date: %02d/%02d/%02d\n", month, date, year);

printf("Student Trial-1 Trial-2 Trial-3 Trial-4 Average\n");

while (x < 10) {
    realTest = 0;       
    scanf("%d %f %f %f %f", &id, &t1, &t2, &t3, &t4);
    if (t1>0)
        realTest += 1;
    if (t2>0)
        realTest += 1;
    if (t3>0)
        realTest += 1;
    if (t4>0)
        realTest += 1;
    avg_trial = (t1+t2+t3+t4)/realTest;
    if (realTest == 0)
        avg_trial = 0.000;          
    if (id<1000) { 
        printf("  %d    %.3f   %.3f   %.3f   %.3f   %.3f\n", id, t1, t2, t3, t4, avg_trial);
        x++;
        }
    else {
        printf(" %d    %.3f   %.3f   %.3f   %.3f   %.3f\n", id, t1, t2, t3, t4, avg_trial);
        x++;
    }
    if (avg_trial < min && avg_trial > 0) {
        min = avg_trial;
        min_user = id;
    }

}

 ms = min * 1000;
 printf("\nStudent %d had the lowest average of %.3f seconds (%d milliseconds)\n", min_user, min, ms);

return 0;
}
```

This is my failed code that includes the process_student function:
     #include

```
 int main(void)
 {

 int month = 0;
 int date = 0;
 int year = 0;
 int x = 0;
 int id = 0;
 int min_user = 0;
 int ms = 0;
 float min = 10000000;
 float t1 = 0;
 float t2 = 0; 
 float t3 = 0;
 float t4 = 0;
 float avg_trial = 0;

scanf("%d %d %d", &month, &date, &year);
printf("\nStudy Date: %02d/%02d/%02d\n", month, date, year);

printf("Student Trial-1 Trial-2 Trial-3 Trial-4 Average\n");

ms = process_student(min) * 1000;
printf("\nStudent %d had the lowest average of %.3f seconds (%d milliseconds)\n", min_user, min, ms);

 int process_student(void) {
float t1, t2, t3, t4, avg_trial, min;   
int min_user;
int realTest = 0;       

while (x < 10) {    
scanf("%d %f %f %f %f", &id, &t1, &t2, &t3, &t4);
if (t1>0)
    realTest += 1;
if (t2>0)
    realTest += 1;
if (t3>0)
    realTest += 1;
if (t4>0)
    realTest += 1;
avg_trial = (t1+t2+t3+t4)/realTest;
if (realTest == 0)
    avg_trial = 0.000;
if (id<1000) { 
    printf("  %d    %.3f   %.3f   %.3f   %.3f   %.3f\n", id, t1, t2, t3, t4, avg_trial);
    x++;
}
else {
    printf(" %d    %.3f   %.3f   %.3f   %.3f   %.3f\n", id, t1, t2, t3, t4, avg_trial);
    x++;
}
if (avg_trial < min && avg_trial > 0) {
    min = avg_trial;
    min_user = id;
}

}

return min;
return min_user;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: ...why? Aside from the fact that this feature doesn't exist, why does this program *need* a nested function at all?

Comment: Basically this is illegal C code, nested functions are not allowed in C. Pull the function out of main and you should be fine.

Comment: Your post would greatly benefit from proper code formatting. It could even help you avoid having double `return` statements!

Comment: 90% of your posted code is irrelevant for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define your nested function before main, or add a declaration before main or in a header and define it elsewhere. There doesn't seem to be a reason for you to need a nested function.

Nested functions are not legal ISO C. The GNU C compiler allows them as an extension. But again, there seems to be no reason to not declare and define `process_student()` as a standard function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your function like this.

add this to the very top line of your program

```
int process_student(float min);
```

you need to change the "void" to "float min" so you can pass a variable to your function.

Then basically copy and paste your entire function from within your program to below it. You will need to redeclare variables within your function.

A brief explination of how a function works,

```
int functionName(int sentvariable1 int sentvariable2);
```

//functionName will recive two interger values from the main program "sentvariable1" and "intsentvariable2" and will return an interger value.

it would be called from the main program like this

```
x = functionName(a,b)
```

with x,a and b all being declared somewhere in your main function.